# What will be the logic if I want to validate a "Log-In" forms 'mail-id' & 'password' from an array that store multiple of users data in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, filter

What will be the logic if I want to validate a "Log-In" forms 'mail-id' & 'password' from an array that store multiple of users data in localstorage(JavaScript)?

I,ve tried to store data in Sign-Up form and individually stored the credential in key's but with the new entered data, previous was deleted ! And I don't know how to fetch data from an array in localstrorage.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. Show us what you tried, instead of just describing it in vague terms.